# Multiple delegate assignments and call in a C# card game action sctruture

Tags: c#, methods, architecture, delegates

I'm working on an Card Game development in C#, and I don't know how to do the following:

I have my Card class, which has a List of actions that are attacks in which that card can perform.

These attacks are a custom class named Act (in which I called Rules in the example).

When I load my cards I call an Inicialize method that I created that inicialize the List of cards, as well as the List of Attacks of each card.

I Want to be able to express my Attacks as an multiple Method call with parameters that will be called only when I call that Attack for execute.

For example, something like that

```
ActionList = new List<CardRule>();
        ActionList.Add(new CardRule()
        {
            Description = "Cause 20 damage, then causes burn status.",
            Rules = Damage(20).CauseStatus(Status.Burn);
        });
```

I want to define the action(which I called Rules) as an multiple method call, passing parameters,

And call that Rules.Execute() to perform all method call, etc..

I Know that its something related to delegates, but I don't know how to do this calling multiple methods with predefined parameters.

Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english, I'm new at Stack Overflow also..

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by a "nested method call"? Are you mostly looking for how you need to define your Rules property to make the above syntax work?

Comment: For example, I want to define the rules as Rules = Damage(20).CauseStatus(Status.Burn),  I want to define as an multiple method call, sorry its not nested, I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't actually a delegate, but a class which tracks what needs to be done. This is a pattern used often by fluent APIs, but it's relatively simple to create something for your example.

For your example, you may have an IActionConfiguration interface, for example:

```
public interface IActionConfiguration
{
    void PerformAction(MyTarget target);
}
```

Now, you'll want a few different implementations. For example, one which represents damage:

```
class DamageActionConfiguration : IActionConfiguration
{
    private int m_damageStrength;

    public DamageActionConfiguration(int strength)
    {
        m_damageStrength = strength;
    }

    public void PerformAction(MyTarget target)
    {
        target.Health -= strength;
    }
}
```

And another one to represent a status effect:

```
class CauseStatusActionConfiguration : IActionConfiguration
{
    private Status m_status;

    public CauseStatusActionConfiguration(Status status)
    {
        m_status = status;
    }

    public void PerformAction(MyTarget target)
    {
        target.StatusEffects.Add(m_status);
    }
}
```

Now, you'll also one an implementation which represents multiple actions.

```
class CompositeActionConfiguration : IActionConfiguration
{
    private IActionConfiguration m_firstWrappedConfiguration;
    private IActionConfiguration m_secondWrappedConfiguration;

    public CompositeActionConfiguration(IActionConfiguration first, IActionConfiguration second)
    {
        m_firstWrappedConfiguration = first;
        m_secondWrappedConfiguration = second;
    }

    public void PerformAction(MyTarget target)
    {
        m_firstWrappedConfiguration.PerformAction();
        m_secondWrappedConfiguration.PerformAction();
    }
}
```

This is incredibly simplified, but good enough for our example. Now you have a class (CompositeActionConfiguration) which can represent multiple actions - all you need is the magic that lets you chain them together easily.

```
public static class ActionRules
{

    //First, you want a few static methods which can start a chain:
    public static IActionConfiguration Damage(int strength)
    {
        return new DamageActionConfiguration(strength);
    }

    public static IActionConfiguration Status(Status status)
    {
        return new CauseStatusActionConfiguration(status);
    }

    // Next, some extension methods which allow you to chain things together
    // This is really the glue that makes this whole solution easy to use
    public static IActionConfiguration WithDamage(this IActionConfiguration source, int strength)
    {
        return new CompositeActionConfiguration(source, Damage(strength));
    }

    public static IActionConfiguration WithStatus(this IActionConfiguration source, Status status)
    {
        return new CompositeActionConfiguration(source, Status(status));
    }
}
```

That's it. This gives you a solution which does more or less what you want. You would define your Rules property as an IActionConfiguration, then you can consume it like this:

```
var card = new CardRule()
{
    Description = "Cause 20 damage, then causes burn status.",
    Rules = ActionRules.Damage(20).WithStatus(Status.Burn);
};

card.PerformAction(target);
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing! This was exactly what I was searching for! Thanks!